# binary privilege based on users execution

Tags: linux, python-2.7, linux-device-driver, freebsd

I have tpdump command , when I run the command with admin tcpdump should run as a root privileges . And when I run same tcpdump command with user1 it should run as normal privilege .

I mean , binary should have the different privileges based on user's who is executing . for example if the binary runs with root , it should have root privilege .And if it runs with user1 then it  should have normal privilege.

Example-1:   for admin

```
# tcpdump -x /data/temp/test.cap
#ls -ld  tcpdump  
  -r-sr-xr-x  1 root  my  43305 Aug  5 11:48 /data/bin/tcpdump
#
```

Example-2: user1

```
# tcpdump -x /data/tmp/test1.cap
#ls -ld tcpdump  
 -r-sr-xr-x  1 user1  my  43305 Aug  5 11:48 /data/bin/tcpdump
#
```

Note: tcpdump is a root binary.
-x to capture the packets into file

Comment: What is the question? I don't see any question marks.

Comment: My doubt here is that for a binary(say tcpdump) is it possible to have different privileges for different users? i.e when login with user1 it should have privileges as shown in `Exaple-2` and when we login with admin it should have privileges as shown in `Example-1` in my initial update.

Comment: Is it possible for a binary(say tpdump), a normal users should run "tcpdump" with their normal privileges. Unless "tcpdump" required to run in promiscuous mode, it shouldn't require root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how permissions work when SUID bit isn't set (which **is** set for tcpdump). See `man chmod` and its `s` permission symbol.